# Zoom In/Out with mousewheel in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

There are a few keymap entries for scrolling in the 2D view section. How do I override these specifically for the compositor to be able to zoom in/out with the mousewheel while leaving scrolling behavior alone in other panels?